# auth()->user returns null in laravel 8 and backpackforlaravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, registration, laravel-backpack

I am using [Bapckpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com) for Laravel, for frontend I want to create custom registration. After successful registration `auth()->user()` returns `null`? Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: If i remember correctly sometimes backpack caches weird parts of the app, try php artisan cache:clear and see if it helps. And what is your session env set to?

Answer (score 1):

if you have created your own registration page, just inserting the record into the database won't make the user logged in. for that purpose you can use `Auth::login()` or `auth()->loginUsingId()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! `Auth:login()` helped me.